# Create a Dictionary from a Dataframe With the Index as the Keys

Tags: python, pandas

`df.to_dict()` creates a nested dictionary where the headers form the keys, `{column:{index:value}}`.

Is there an easy way to create a dictionary where the index forms the keys, `{index:column:value}}`? Or even `{index:(column,value)}`?

I can create the dictionary and then invert it, but I was wondering if this can be done in a single step.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Transpose the dataframe before you use `df.to_dict`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 3, 5], 'b': [2, 7, 5]})

print(df)
#    a  b
# 0  1  2
# 1  3  7
# 2  5  5

print(df.transpose().to_dict())
# {0: {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, 
#  1: {'a': 3, 'b': 7}, 
#  2: {'a': 5, 'b': 5}}
```

Comment: Well that was embarrassingly simple. Thanks.